# Create database on sdcard and not accessible or display in FileExplorer in Android

Tags: android, database, sd-card

I develop one application in android and i want to create a database on sdcard but i want to it secure that database file should not display in any file explorer. user should not get the location of database file.

In database, data is very important.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Any thing on sdcard can be acessed by all application (unless you are using SecureElement) 
In case you don't want other apps to access it simply encrypt it.

Comment: but then they could still delete it.

Comment: i store database on sdcard. ok and i use file explorer on Android table, Open FileExplorer and go to that database file and i remove databse from FileExplorer. My Database is deleted. and when i open my android application it does not work. it gives so many errors.

Comment: fi you want your data to be secure then store it in the asset folder, not in SD Card

Comment: In my application database creating at runtime on first screen, and then transaction on other screen. So if i create database in asset folder how it works? it works normally.